# What to do when missing some data in a date series?

Tags: sql, django

I am trying to graph a count over time from multiple sources, but having issues when the collection job fails on one (or more, but not all) of the sources.

Suppose I have a set of data like:

```
 date       |  count
---------------------
 10-11-2013 |   50
 11-11-2013 |   52
 13-11-2013 |   63
```

and another like

```
 date       |  count
---------------------
 10-11-2013 |   15
 11-11-2013 |   19
 12-11-2013 |   17
 13-11-2013 |   20
```

for whatever reason I am missing the data entry on the 12th for the first one. If I am just working with this single object then I can graph it fine by just skipping that element and the line will just be inaccurate on that day.

The problem I get is when I have multiple sources, and at least one of them succeeded in reporting its results for that day. I have a queryset that gets a sum of the all the daily counts:

```
DailyCount.objects.values('date').annotate(count=Sum('count')).order_by('date')
```

The results from this show a much lower number on the entry for the 12th. Making the graph look very wrong whenever this happens.

```
 date       |  count
---------------------
 10-11-2013 |   65
 11-11-2013 |   71
 12-11-2013 |   17
 13-11-2013 |   83
```

Is there a way to have my queryset use the previous date's count if it doesn't exist? I thought about adding the previous day's count to the database, but it doesn't seem right to be adding some (probably wrong) data to the database when I can't verify it.

ideally I think it would look like:

```
 date       |  count
---------------------
 10-11-2013 |   65
 11-11-2013 |   71
 12-11-2013 |   69
 13-11-2013 |   83
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how you display the graph. In [`pandas`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pandas) you can store time series of data as well and they provide exactly the functionality you describe: backfill or forward fill any missing values by using a previous or future value (i.e., [`pandas.DataFrame.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html)). On one hand using that library for just that functionality is overkill but you may find it useful if you're planning on doing more data manipulation.

I don't think a Django `QuerySet` can fill in missing values as it was not built to do that. However you could compute it manually by taking the values from the query result and computing the right daily values before displaying the graph.